# Packer or config structure problem

Tags: neovim, packer

I'm trying to port my nvim configuration to another desktop, but I can't seem to figure out how to make `packer` work.
I enter nvim and I don't see any errors regarding `packer` at startup, just about plugins that I don't have installed precisely because I can't make `packer` work.
[Here](https://github.com/enrico223/.config/tree/main/nvim) my config.
I followed the guide on github and copy-pasted

```
git clone --depth 1 https://github.com/wbthomason/packer.nvim\
 ~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim
```

Sourcing my init.lua throws me the error `loop or previous error loading module 'enrico'`, so I guess it may be a tree problem.
Here my configuration tree

```
.config/nvim/
├── after
│   └── plugin
│       └── color.lua
├── colors
├── init.lua
├── lua
│   └── enrico
│       ├── init.lua
│       ├── keymap.lua
│       ├── packer.lua
│       └── set.lua
├── plugin
│   └── packer_compiled.lua
├── spell
└── UltiSnips
```

Any hint is much appreciated

Comment: Do you have the file: `~/.local/share/nvim/site/pack/packer/start/packer.nvim`?

Comment: Yes, that wasn't the problem. I managed to solve it but Idk how. I'll update the question later because it could still be useful for someone.